Issue with dynamically loading React components in a unified mobile and web project: Module parse failed error with expo-barcode-generator on web
I have a project where both a mobile app and a web app are integrated into the same server and repository. The React components are loaded dynamically based on the environment like this:
import React from "react";
class Sheet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      componentLoaded: false,
      Component: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    if (!!process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ROOT) {
      this.setState({ Component: require('./mobile').default, componentLoaded: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ Component: require('./web').default, componentLoaded: true });
    }
  };
  render = () => {
    if (!this.state.componentLoaded) {
      return null; // or a loading indicator, e.g. <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    return React.createElement(this.state.Component, this.props);
  };
}
export default Sheet;


This setup works fine on mobile, but when I run the web application, I encounter the following error related to the expo-barcode-generator library:
: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (44:4)
|
|   return (

<Svg
|       x={0}
|       y={0}

Here are the files that reference the expo-barcode-generator and react-native-view-shot libraries:
import * as Print from 'expo-print';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { captureRef } from 'react-native-view-shot';

import ProductionOrderSheet from "../../ProductionOrderSheet"

const printSheet = async (viewRef) => {
    try {
        const uri = await captureRef(viewRef, {
            format: "png",
            quality: 1.0
        })...
};

const Sheet = (props) => {
    const { appContext, type, sheet } = props;
    
    switch (type) {
        case "productionOrderSheet":
            return (
                <ProductionOrderSheet
                    {...sheet}
                    type={"productionOrderSheet"}
                    printSheet={printSheet}
                    appContext={appContext}
                />
            );

        default:
            throw new Error(`(Sheet) the sheet type ${type} not found`);
    }
}

export default Sheet

import Table from "../../Table";
import Button from '../../Button';
import Container from "../../Container"
import TextFormatter from "../../TextFormatter"
import { Barcode } from 'expo-barcode-generator';

const MobileProductionOrderSheet = (props) => {
    ...
    const getHeader = () => {
        return (
                    <Barcode
                        value={productionLot}
                        options={{ format: 'CODE128', background: 'white', height: 70, fontSize: 18 }}
                    />
                </Container>
            </Container>
        )
    }
    ...

package.json:
{
  "name": "@monorepo/appmobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.10.8",
    "@expo/ngrok": "^4.1.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.15",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.10.0",
    "core-js": "^3.37.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.21",
    "expo-barcode-generator": "^3.0.2",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "^3.0.6",
    "expo-print": "^13.0.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~7.0.5",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "graphql": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-media-query": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.19.6",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


Commenting out the library imports: I commented out the imports for expo-barcode-generator and react-native-view-shot, and the code worked on the web but not on mobile, as the component could not be used.
// import { Barcode } from 'expo-barcode-generator';
// import { captureRef } from 'react-native-view-shot';
Commenting out the conditional mobile import: I also tried commenting out the conditional import for mobile, which made the web work, but then I couldn't use the component on mobile.
if (!!process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ROOT) {
  // this.setState({ Component: require('./mobile').default, componentLoaded: true });
} else {
  this.setState({ Component: require('./web').default, componentLoaded: true });
}


Finally, I attempted to use dynamic require for the libraries, like this:
if (!!process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ROOT) {
    const Barcode = require('expo-barcode-generator');
}

but it not works

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This error occurs because nextJs tries to resolve and process all imports during the build phase.
Go to next config custom webpack config and create an alias to ignore imports, this way:
nextConfig = {
   webpack: (config) => {

       config.resolve.alias['react-native-view-shot'] = false;
       config.resolve.alias['expo-barcode-generator'] = false;
   }
}

